# Create a virtual machine for development with Vagrant

Tags: bash, automation, vagrant, ansible, virtualization

I am using nodejs with ansible and vagrant

I need to create a new machine for development with such things:

on every `vagrant up`  I need to do:

- run this script (to install all needed soft for development):

  > bash <(wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thoughtbot/laptop/master/linux)
- NPM install on every submodule in my project
- install and run mongodb service

How I can set these stuff to do automatically in vagrant or ansible?

Comment: you dont need to run everytime, run it once then it will be done on further `vagrant up`

Comment: sure but I have a bunch of such commands, after vagrant destroy or install to other host I dont want to do this manually @FrédéricHenri

Comment: ok clear, but did you start with something ? pretty sure that ansible playbook for mongo exists on internet. Generally on SO it is required that you show off that you've done your part of google search and are blocking on a specific issue that other can help you solve.

Comment: @FrédéricHenri sure, just wrote this post in rush

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options:

1. vagrant up, install your dependencies and repackage it as a box with: vagrant package or vagrant box repackage
2. Use chef/puppet/ansible provisioners, or even the shell provisioner. This will allow it to happen on vagrant up or vagrant provision
3. Roll your own in ruby and have vagrant run it (a vagrantfile is basically just ruby). I don't recommend this way.

I personally recommend 2 even though its the slowest (requires you to do all the owrk every time you destroy and up). 1 is a really good choice but I tend to keep vagrant as close to base state as possible so that no surprises pop up during deployment. And it makes it easier to share across people if you don't have to constantly re-package it and maintain that .box